# Need help understanding the expected value of a product of random variables using cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $t_{1}<\dots<t_{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Define the finite-dimensional cumulative distribution function $F_{t_{1},\dots,t_{n}}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to[0,1]$ of a random vector $X=(X_{t_{1}},\dots,X_{t_{n}}):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by:
$$F_{t_{1},\dots,t_{n}}(x)=\mathbb{P}_{X_{t_{1}},\dots,X_{t_{n}}}(x)=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_{t_{j}}\leq x_{j}\}\right),\quad x=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.$$
The expected value of the random variable $X_{t_{1}}:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined as:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t_{1}}]=\int_{\Omega}X_{t_{1}}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,\mathrm{d}F_{t_{1}}(x),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Then, is it true that:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t_{1}}X_{t_{2}}]=\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega}X_{t_{1}}X_{t_{1}}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}_{X_{t_{1}},X_{t_{2}}}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,\mathrm{d}F_{t_{1},t_{2}}(x),\quad x=(x_{1},x_{2})\in\mathbb{R}^{2}?$$

Answer (score 1):

No because $x=(x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$ not $\mathbb R$?

But since $\frac{d^2F(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}=f(x,y)$,

$$\begin{split}E(XY)&=\int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R}xy d^2F(x,y)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty xyf(x,y)dxdy\\
&=\int _\Omega \int _\Omega xy f(x,y)dxdy \end{split}$$

though.

Comment: What is ? Is $S=\mathbb{R}$ or?

Comment: @Miski123 $S$ is the sample space $\Omega$ above

Comment: How so? I mean $F_{t_{1},t_{2}}$ is a function over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ not $\Omega^{2}$, so wouldn't each of the two integrals  be over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Miski123 do you think so? I thought this could be answered without measure theory but maybe I was wrong